# How to customize close button in sticky ads

Tags: css

Hello I hope everyone is doing good. I am using sticky ads on my website, can anyone tell me how can I change style of the close button like this. [close button example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPBBX.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you've got so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this,  create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this. And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

For this, you must first pull an icon from the library like a `fontawesome`. Then you can set the `padding` of it and change the `background` color to the color you want. Then you can adjust their position with the `position` tag. I leave resources for you.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Good Work :)